# How can I add my variables in user object

Tags: joomla-3.x, session, user-groups

I am trying to create vendor panel.

In that I need to identify the user is vendor or normal user.

For that I need to add session variable or variable in user object.

But how can I achieve that.

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Why not just create separate user groups called "Vendor" and "End-User" and assign the users to those appropriate groups?

Comment: I did that, but after that how can I get that group name @MichaelYaeger

Comment: if you want to check if a user is a member of a particular group, use:
`<?php $user = JFactory::getUser(); if(in_array(11,$user->groups)) /*Do something...*/; ?>` where "11" is the ID of the group in question. The ID of the groups you are using can be found in the Administrator under Users > Groups.

Comment: @MichaelYaegers answer is the correct method of determining a users group.

Answer (score 1):

According to this tutorial https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables it is quite simple

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->setUserState("$option.state_variable", "state1");
```

Documentation of this function can be found here https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JApplicationCms.html#method_getUserState

Maybe for your case it's better to use `set` and `get` functions on the user's object. I've never used them, so I don't know if they are permanent or how exactly they behave. Check them here https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUser.html#method_set

Comment: This is more for setting a userState variable. I think what the OP is looking for is how to get a users specific group.

Comment: Yes you are right, the best solution would be to create "Vendor" group and then the specific access level, doesn't need to play with any state variables.